# Execute a script shell automatically on startup in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, startup

I did a lot of research on this and I saw a lot of ways on how to do this. However, none of it seems working for me. For example, I did something like this:

> ~/.config/upstart/text.config

I created a .config file under the directory mentioned above and wrote the following command (testScript.sh below is the script that i wanted to run) :

```
start on startup 
task 
exec /path/to/testScript.sh
```

Another way that i tried, I wrote something like this in rc.local file:

```
sudo -H /etc/init.d/testScript.sh start
```

And I put my testScript.sh in init.d. Both of these ways didn't work for me. The system didn't give me any errors or remarks. Did i make a mistake somewhere or is there another way to do this? So that my script execute automatically on the startup of the system.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you execute `update-rc.d testScript.sh enable` the proper links will be created in the various /etc/rc?.d directories. Read up on the boot process. A good place to start is https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/. Although newer releases of Linux systems also use systemd and Upstart.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44360295/4957508

Comment: `crontab` it maybe?

Answer (score 9):

Why not just use plain `cron` for it? 
Edit `/etc/crontab` as superuser and add a line

```
@reboot     root    /path/to/testScript.sh
```

that should do the trick without any more hassle.
(see `man 5 crontab` for more `cron` options)

Comment: Great solution, unless you want to be sure that a specific service has been started. For example `docker`

Comment: sshuttle required to use systemd, cron did not work

Comment: In this answer, is `root` the user to run the script i assume?

Comment: @ZillaYT: see `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 3):

Lets Do some check First,

1: Check weather you script is running properly on os.(means is it not getting any error or getting stuck somewhere).

2: you need to create a systemd startup script Eg. testScript.service and place it into /etc/systemd/system/ directory. You can add script as the example of such systemd startup script below:

```
[Unit]
After=mysql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/testScript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Copy script to `/usr` path and Before rebooting system you need to make your script executable:

```
cp /path/to/testScript.sh /usr/local/bin/testScript.sh
chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/testScript.sh
```

3: Next, install systemd service unit and enable it so it will be executed at the boot time:

```
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/testScript.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable testScript.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/testScript-sp
```

Hope this works well , i have tested in my system and working fine..
Still you have on mo option putting it in crond with Add the line `@reboot`.